# Where on the Eastern Coast of the US can one find beaches beneath scenic ocean cliffs or bluffs?

Tags: usa, beaches

And what are the names of some of those beaches?

Comment: There are thousands of miles of coastline on the East Coast and many of those are beaches. Could you perhaps be more specific about what exactly you're looking for?

Comment: Bluffs/cliffs on the Atlantic coast of the US aren't all that common, in my experience.  I'm not sure that this question is actually all that broad.

Comment: @Michael Seifert; agreed. Perhaps the Earth Sciences stack may be better suited to respond? As I recall from uni geology, the eastern US has a submergent coast, formed when sea levels rise and cover land. While Maine does have rocky hills along its shore, some quite high, it was the rising seas. An emergent coast forms when the sea level drops, characterized by wave-cut cliffs.

Comment: Are Zach and Zach_is_my_name the same person?

Comment: @Blaszard why are you doing insignificant edits on old and closed posts? Is it for rep? It's not particularly useful :-)

Comment: @Dorothy I was trying to get a new badge. Is it against the policy?

Comment: @Blaszard not the best way to go about it... far better to watch new questions and, if you have either knowledge or well-versed in teasing relevant source references on the internet, post an answer. Another helpful way is doing clarifying edits to new posts to improve the chance of getting a good response.